# angular js merge 2 objects into third one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to merge object1 and object2 into object3. The values corresponding to the keys matching should be updated and the unmatching keys should be ignored. How to do it?

```
var object1 = {
  "pii" : "val1",
  "loc" : "val2"
}

var object2 = {
  "rrb" : "val3",
  "voc" : "val4"
}

var object3{
 "pii": "",
      "loc" : "",
     "rrb" : "",
      "voc" : "",
      "obj3item" : "",
      "obj3val" : ""
}
```

### Result object

```
var object3 ={
  "pii": "val1",
  "loc" : "val2",
 "rrb" : "val3",
  "voc" : "val4",
  "obj3item" : "val5",
  "obj3val" : "item4"

}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically extending an object.

This code will do your job:

```
function merge_options(obj1,obj2){
    var obj3 = {};
    for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
    for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
    return obj3;
}
```